# Android: Update horizontal progess dialog when creating large database with dbhelper

Tags: android, progress

I have been searching for this for days.  I have a very large database which is loaded from an SQL file.  The code for this is in the DbHelper class file and so, as I create an instance of the helper, if the database does not exist the creation takes place.

I have a progress spinner showing but I would like to be able to show a progress bar which increments as the file is created.

Most examples show how to do this but not how to send a value from the helper back to the main activity.

The helper is called from a thread in main.  Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something that an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) does very well.
 When you invoke the publishProgress method from inside doInBackground, the onProgressUpdate method gets called on the UI thread and you can update your progress bar from there.

Here's a couple of good examples: 
http://labs.makemachine.net/2010/05/android-asynctask-example/
https://sites.google.com/site/androidhowto/how-to-1/create-a-custom-progress-bar-using-asynctask

Comment: ,sorry, I'm new to this commenting lark ;o)  What I have at the moment is my main activity sets up a thread which calls a small function which, in turn calls the DbHelper class (separate file!)  I hope this will work when I try to show you the code.           new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
             loadData();
                pd.dismiss();
            }
        }).start();  and      private void loadData()
    {
     DbAdapter mDbHelper;
     mDbHelper = new DbAdapter(this);
     mDbHelper.close();
    }    See next comment ...

Comment: Then the OnCreate in the helper reads a text file in the 'raw' resource and creates the database thus ...       @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
         
         boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
            if (dbExist) {
                // do nothing - database already exist
            } else {
         String s;
         int i = 0;
      try {
       InputStream in = mycontext.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.sql1);
       DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
       Document doc = builder.parse(in, null);

Comment: NodeList statements = doc.getElementsByTagName("statement");
       int l = statements.getLength();
       for (i=0; i<l; i++) {
        s = statements.item(i).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
        db.execSQL(s);
        // if i = (l/100) { ** send message back to the progress bar ** }
       }
       //System.out.println("Lines written; " + i);
       
      } catch (Throwable t) {
       System.out.println(t.toString());

      }      I am not sure how to send the message from within the OnCreate in the DbHelper class.  Any further help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry about this, there must be an easier way to communicate ;o)  As you can see, I have a for-next loop which I can use to update the progress bar.  If the main activity is on the screen, is it possible for the DbHelper class to instigate the progress dialog?

Comment: Alan, you should be able to edit your post and add the code there. It will be a lot easier to read as part of the original post. Please do that and I'll see if I can help you out.

Comment: Hi again, I have changed my strategy and am now loading the database behind a splash screen using asynctask as you suggested.  Thanks for your help.  It was too complicated trying to do it the other way. Best wishes, Alan ...

Comment: Great to hear Alan, glad it is working for you now. Please mark this answer as accepted if you feel it is correct.